# Scaffolding for WPF using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, scaffolding

Can anyone tell me if its possible (if some utility exists??) to create scaffolding taking into consideration MVVM with WPF.

My idea here is i seem to have a lot fo data access forms, and of course i would like to Customize them but initially i would like a quick way of providing the form i.e. ALL controls placed on them and Binded to the mvvm ??

Maybe I am asking a lot?

Basically the forms would be created automatically for me and later i could go in a customize them and move them around but initially they just would work.

Scaffolding - I am stealing the term from web development but i presume it still exists here in wpf?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

There is a product from a company named [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/). They have exactly the product you are describing. See a video of the product [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILWdnTsIDfc)

Answer (score 3):

Scaffolding is a way to automatically generate UIs for each table in the database. It lets you create a functional UI for viewing and editing data based on the schema of the data. Here are a couple of resources for WPF scaffolding.

There is a WPF scaffolding article on the Code Project website: [WPF CRUD Generator (Scaffolding)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36975/WPF-CRUD-Generator-Scaffolding)

There is also a Codeplex project that could be helpful: [WPF Scaffolder](http://wpfscaffolder.codeplex.com)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of anything to help with the views, but [this tool](http://clarius.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=ViewModel%20Tool&referringTitle=Home) is supposed to help with view models. I've never used it so can't vouch for how effective it is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.. that will come in handy.. i also found this http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/xaml-power-toys/    which allows you to hook up the forms from models..

Thanks once again