# Dynamic CRUD screen template in WPF ( MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dynamic, generics, crud

I'm working on a WPF application .
We're using the MVVM pattern.
What we need is a generic template screen for all our reference data entities ( master tables).
Is there a scaffolding framework/library available to accomplish this in WPF .
If not then could anyone provide me a few pointers on how I could start implementing this myself ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704337/scaffolding-for-wpf-using-mvvm

Comment: And this Google search: http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=WPF+scaffolding turned up some promising results.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out this nice article from Markus Egger for Code magazine, where he describes how to quickly create simple forms using a custom panel type.

http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=1011071